# How can I give transition effect for this code?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./About.css";
import About_Main from "../components/About_Main";
import About_Data1 from "../components/About_Data1";
import About_Data2 from "../components/About_Data2";

class About extends React.Component {
  state = {
    main: {
      display:"block",
      opacity:1
    },
    data: {
      display:"none",
      opacity:0
    }
  };
  changeSelect = id => {
    if (id === "select1") {
      this.setState({
        main: {
          display:"block",
          opacity:1
        },
        data: {
          display:"none",
          opacity:0
      }});
    } else if (id === "select2") {
      this.setState({
        main: {
          display:"none",
          opacity:0
        },
        data: {
          display:"block",
          opacity:1
        }});
    }
  };
  clickHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.changeSelect(event.target.id);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="selects">
          <div
            id="select1"
            className="select"
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          ></div>
          <div
            id="select2"
            className="select"
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          ></div>
        </section>
        <section className="about">
          <div
            className="about_div"
            style={{ display: this.state.main.display, opacity: this.state.main.opacity }}
          >
            <About_Main></About_Main>
          </div>
          <div
            className="about_data"
            style={{ display: this.state.data.display, opacity:this.state.data.opacity }}
          >
            <About_Data1></About_Data1>
            <About_Data2></About_Data2>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

By clicking 2 different buttons, I want to show only one out of two.
Also, I like to give a transition effect so I used opacity. But it is not working!
Is this the only way to set style property using javascript in react?
Can't I use `querySelector` or something else?
I feel like javascript is much easier than react

Comment: You could toggle a className instead of manipulating the style directly; but to be honest you should narrow the scope of your question - you are asking multiple things at once.

Comment: it'l be easier to help if you include a minimal working example